# How to add a Cell programmatically to a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

I want to add an extra cell to each column created where its value is from the cells in each row. I have this code but doesn't work:

```
i = 0;

                Double X1 = Convert.ToDouble(DGV_Points.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                Double X2 = Convert.ToDouble(DGV_Points.Rows[i++].Cells[6].Value);

                Double LapLength = X1 - X1;

                this.DGV_Points.Rows.Add();
                this.DGV_Points.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = LapLength;
                this.DGV_Points.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = LapLength;
```

I have also tried this exaample:

```
 foreach (var item in _model.SelectedItems)
            {
                var row = new DataGridViewRow();
                var codeCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                codeCell.Items.AddRange(ItemCode.Items);
                codeCell.Value = ItemCode.Items.GetListItem(item.Code);
                var nameCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
                nameCell.Items.AddRange(ItemName.Items);
                nameCell.Value = ItemName.Items.GetListItem(item.Name);
                row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = item.Id });
                row.Cells.Add(codeCell);
                row.Cells.Add(nameCell);
                row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = item.Units });
                row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = item.Quantity });
                row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = item.PriceLt });
                row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell { Value = item.PriceEu });
                itemView.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

But it also doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: As an aside, ".Rows[i++]" doesn't do what you think it does. It still returns Row zero. You want to use ++i instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

- You need to have a `Column` first, then you can replace any `Cell` in the `Column` by whatever type of `Cell` you want to create:

---

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn normalColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
DGV_Points.Columns.Insert(yourColumnIndex, normalColumn);
DGV_Points.Rows.Add(11);  // we need at least one row where we can insert a cell
DataGridViewComboBoxCell aCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
DGV_Points.Rows[someRowIndex].Cells[yourColumnIndex] = aCell;
```

- Or you create that `Column` to have the `ColumnType` you want and all `Cells` in the `Column` will have the right `Type` from the beginning:

---

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboCol.HeaderText = "yourHeaderText";
DGV_Points.Columns.Insert(yourColumnIndex, comboCol);
```

Note that the first method creates only as many `DataGridViewComboBoxCells` as you make it to whereas the second way immediatly create a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` in each `Row`. It is up to you to decide what you want..

Instead or `Inserting` at a given position you may want to simply `Add` the `Column`. The `Add` method returns the `Index` of the new `Column`.

Since we are adding a `DataGridViewComboBoxCells`  here is an example how you can fill the `Items` of the new dropdown cell:

```
List<string> items1 = new List<string> (){ "111", "222", "333", "444", "555" };
((DataGridViewComboBoxCell)DGV_Points.Rows[2].Cells[0] ).Items
                                     .AddRange(items1.ToArray());
DGV_Points.Rows[2].Cells[0].Value = "222";
```

This fills the dropdownlist of the cell in row 2, column 0 with five string values and select the value to be "222". Note that this way you must fill the `Items` of each `Cell` and you can fill each one with a different list of values to choose from.

You can also set an individual `Cell's DataSource`: `aCell.DataSource = items1;` or you can set it for the `Column`: `comboCol.DataSource = items1;`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However after a bit of alteration in your first code I managed to insert a new column programmatically. So, I'm having problems with inserting values in the new cells created. I have tried all the below codes:
Code #1:
int i = 0;

                System.Object obj = (System.Object)DGV_Points.Rows[i].DataBoundItem;
                obj.Equals(51);

Code #2:
int i = 0;
                DGV_Points.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = 51;
                DGV_Points.Rows[++i].Cells[1].Value = 35;
                DGV_Points.Rows.Add();

Comment: Code #3:
int i = 0;
                DGV_Points.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
                DGV_Points.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = 51;
                DGV_Points.Rows[++i].Cells[1].Value = 35;
                DGV_Points.EndEdit();

Code #4:
int i = 0;
                string cellValue = DGV_Points.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue.ToString();
                DGV_Points.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = 51;
                DGV_Points.Update();

Do you know how to do so?

Comment: There is more than one way to fill a Cell and its Items . I have added one to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells[1].Value = 50.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

OR

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells["Column2"].Value = "XYZ";
row.Cells["Column6"].Value = 50.2;
yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```